# Syntax Error for bad input after lots of text in text based RPG

Tags: python

I'm working hard on a small text-based RPG, and I ran into this issue:

In the beginning, I asked the player if they wanted to go left or right, and named that soldierdecisionone. After working through the entire story if the player chose left, I started on right. But when I said:

if soldierdecisionone=='Right' or soldierdecisionone=='right': input(...),

It said that everything after 'if soldierdecisionone=='Left'...' had a syntax error. If this doesn't make sense, I have here a link to a Google Doc with my code.

Thank you so much if you take the time to answer my confusing question, haha

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qrnZ6cX2hZoXmKitJpWoIhcJfQF-3KVOJG4e1ftsUBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Paste the code here

Comment: To save some space, `string.upper()` will convert the input into all upper case so you don't have to write `or` for each capitalization. Instead only saying `if string.upper() == "UPPERCASE STRING":`

Comment: Your google docs link has mangled the indentation of your code.  Unfortunately, indentation matters in Python, so we have no way of understanding your code in its current form.  Please edit your post to include the full code (with correct indentation) as well as the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems that `soldierdecisionone` is not defined before you try to compare it to `'Right'` or `'Left'`.

Try adding `solderdecisionone = ''` above that line of code. You have similar errors with other variables like `soldierattackorc`

Be sure to define all of the variables before you use them.

Comment: Hello! I don't know what you mean by defining it, I believe I already have. My code says _if rpgclass=='S' or rpgclass=='s': soldierdecisionone=input('...')_. Doesn't this define soldierdecisionone? Thank you for you answer

Comment: Defining a variable means you are telling the computer, "hey, this is a variable, so if i use this keyword again, know it's a variable." Python is special where you don't have a keyword, but you need to give a variable a value before you try and use it. In your example, you are comparing rpgclass to 'S', but rpgclass doesn't have a value. How are you supposed to compare something that doesn't have a value? You might also be getting confused with == vs =, where == is an equality operator and = is an assignment operator. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm